# Magento, add VAT nr to billing address

Tags: php, mysql, magento, billing

It is possible in Magento to add a VAT number to your account but in Belgium it's more common to add a VAT number to your billing address. Is this possible in some kind of way ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, almost anything is possible as Magento is built with php and is completely open-source.  But what you are requesting is not very easy, unfortunately.  You will have to write a custom module to do this, and it's not an easy one to write.

Here are a couple possible options (I haven't tried them) that may get you started:

1. http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_checkoutfieldsmanager.html
2. http://kernelhack.com/?p=37

Good luck!